# Getting the date of 7 days ago from current date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get the date that was 7 days ago starting from current date in python. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using the datetime module? What kind of object do you have - a date object or a datetime object? (Or something else, if you're not using the datetime module?) The lack of detail makes this harder to answer, but in any case, the answer should be easy to find in the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 140):

```
import datetime as DT
today = DT.date.today()
week_ago = today - DT.timedelta(days=7)
```

Answer (score 68):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 6, 10, 29, 37, 596779)
```

If you really just want the date, you can call the date method:

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).date()
datetime.date(2013, 12, 6)
```

Or, work with dates to begin with as suggested by unutbu.