# is there a way to automatically get the date

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

is there a way to automatically fill in the date by `start_date` And `end_date` because i need to make `start_date` 30 days before `end_date` and `end_date` needs to be the current date

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
            for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
                yield start_date + timedelta(n)

        start_date = date(2020, 6, 1)
        end_date = date(2020, 6, 30)
        for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
            print(single_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: The concepts used here answer your question. [Getting the date of 7 days ago from current date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573459/getting-the-date-of-7-days-ago-from-current-date-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
end_date = datetime.today()
start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)

print(end_date)
print(start_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())-datetime.timedelta(days=30)
end_date = datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Upvoting answer. same logic different approach